# CSS Fade Between Background Images on Hover

Tags: image, css, fade, css-transitions

Is there a way that I can do the following?

I have a transparent png sprite that shows a standard picture on the left, and a picture for the :hover state on the right.

Is there a way that I can have the image fade from the left image into the right image on :hover using only css3 transitions? I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
li{-webkit-transition:all 0.5s linear; -moz-transition:all 0.5s linear; -o-transition:all 0.5s linear; transition:all 0.5s linear;}
li{background:url(/img/sprites.png) 0 -50px no-repeat;}
li:hover{background:url(/img/sprites.png) 0 -150px no-repeat;}
```

Now, the above does animate the background, it pans the image across. What I'd like instead of a pan is a fade or dissolve effect.

**UPDATE:** I ended up having to create two elements and just animate the opacities separately. It's a tad messy because I have to specify the exact margins of each element, but I guess it'll work. Thanks for everyones help :)

Answer (score 4):

The latest news on this topic:

Chrome 19 and newer supports background-image transitions:

Demo:
http://dabblet.com/gist/1991345

Additional info:
http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/

Comment: +1 best answer so far. But it's only working in chrome for now

Comment: True, But what about other cross browsers support ??

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified any code to do the actual transition.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg1/

Try this out in your hover style:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: No, I have, sorry, I didn't include that. Opacity would hide the entire list element though, I need it to fade from one background position to another instead of moving the background image.

Comment: @Joe that's very close to what I want. I'm going to have to look through the code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/j5brM/1/

I think this suits all your needs and its a little bit less complicated.

Comment: Thanks for going to the effort, but this still just pans the background image. What I need is a fade effect.

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot what type of animation you needed.
However I tried doing this: [http://jsfiddle.net/ZNsnV/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNsnV/).
It's the best I can get with only css and background images!

Comment: I ended up having to create two elements and just animate the opacities separately. It's a tad messy because I have to specify the exact margins of each element, but I guess it'll work. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can change the opacity of just background images in CSS, so unless you have two separate elements for the background image (one for each position of the sprite) and change the opacity of both of them on hover, I think you’re stuck.

Comment: I was afraid of that. What a shame that they didn't include this in css3.

Comment: Oh: it has been suggested that you could use `:before` to simulate background opacity — see near the bottom of http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/

Comment: I ended up having to create two elements and just animate the opacities separately. It's a tad messy because I have to specify the exact margins of each element, but I guess it'll work. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
li{background:url(/img/sprites.png) 0 -50px no-repeat; background:rgba(80, 125, 200, 0.55);}
li:hover{background:url(/img/sprites.png) 0 -150px no-repeat; background:rgba(100, 125, 175, 0);}
```

should be

```
li{background:url(/img/sprites.png) 0 -50px no-repeat; background-color:rgba(80, 125, 200, 0.55);}
li:hover{background:url(/img/sprites.png) 0 -150px no-repeat; background-color:rgba(100, 125, 175, 0);}
```

not sure if that fixes it or not though.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jack it's kind of hard to visualize the situation without knowing what the sprite is... do you have a development version of the site up somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a tad late. But I was struggling with the same issue for a long time. Also with transparent sprites many solutions don't seem to work.

What I did is this

**HTML**

```
<div class="sprite-one">
  <span class="foo"></span><span class="zen"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sprite-one {
height: 50px
width: 50px
}
.sprite-one span {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
.foo, .zen { 
background-image: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;
-webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
}
.foo {
background-position: 0 0;
opacity: 1;
}
.zen {
background-position: -50px 0;
opacity: 0;
}
.sprite-one:hover .foo {
opacity: 0;
}
.sprite-one:hover .zen {
opacity: 1;
}
```

This is a pure css way & has a bit of a lot of coding.. but seems be the only way I achieved the desired effect! Hope people that also stumble onto this can find some help from this!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="image transition"></li>

css:
.image{
background-image: url("some/file/path.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: XXpx;
height: XXpx;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}

/* DRY */
.transition{
transition: background 0.6s;
-webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
}

.image:hover{
background-image: url("some/file/path_hoverImage.png");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**CSS:-**

li {
    background: url(http://oakdale.squaresystem.co.uk/images/solutions.png) no-repeat left center;
    background-size: 89px;
    padding: 54px 0 54px 130px;
    webkit-transition:all 0.5s linear; 
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s linear; 
    -o-transition:all 0.5s linear; 
    transition:all 0.5s linear;
}

li:hover {
    background-size: 50px
}