# Fade to different div background image on hover

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

For this new website I'm creating, I'm trying to get one background to fade into another when I hover on a link. I don't want the link to change, just the background. I found some good jQuery to get the background to change, but there's no fade effect and my knowledge of jQuery is limited. Here's what I have so far:

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
        <a id="linktomouseover" href="http://delusion.submittable.com/submit" alt="Submit to Delusion" style="position: absolute; width: 275px; height: 99px; top: 354px; left: 263px; display: block;"> </a>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  height:600px;
  width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url(Images/website-header1.png) center top no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
             $("#container a").hover(function() { // Changes the #main divs background to the rel property of the link that was hovered over.
             $("#container").css("background", "url(Images/website-header2.png)");
         }, function() { // Sets the background back to the default on hover out
             $("#container").css("background", "url(Images/website-header1.png)");
             });
        });
</script>
```

If anyone has any other suggestions on how to do this, that would be great. This is just what I found. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: To fade two images at the same time, you would need two images, or in your case two elements with different backgrounds and then fade in/out the elements, as you can't fade just the background property. To fade out, swap images, and then fade in, one element will suffice.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948758/css-fade-between-background-images-on-hover

Comment: One of the images is a black background with white text. That's the background property. I'd like to fade in an image on top of the background, which has a misty quality about it. The background image I have currently doesn't really need to go away or cross fade. The other image just needs to fade in when I hover over the link, which is on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it without ever hiding the link. It also does a nice cross-fade instead of fading out completely, then back in.

Have two div's within `#container` that are absolutely positioned with 100% `width` and `height`, and a `z-index` of -1. Each of these divs contain your background images. You swap them out on hover. In my example I use a background color instead, for expedience sake, but you get the idea.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <a href="#">The Link</a>
</div>
```

...

```
#container {
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#container a {
    color: white;
}

#container div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#one {
    background-color: blue;
}

#two {
    background-color: green;
    display:none;
}
```

...

```
$("#container a").hover(function () {
    $("#container div:visible").fadeOut();
    $("#container div:hidden").fadeIn();
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSpEa/1)